# What are my non-gas alternatives to a wood burning fireplace?

Tags: fireplace

Our house has a wood burning firplace that we want to convert to something else but we have no gas lines in the area. What are our options for heating benefits and esthetics?

Comment: If you have gas in your house at all, it's not difficult to run a line to some where else in your house.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

All very nice and stylish.. Electric fire place! This will be the easiest way to replace your wood fire place. But the cons in most countries is that electric heating is very expensive. Pros are well.. clean and easy. Press a button and set the heat you want. Effects vary and they are not expensive.

**If you want to use gas,**

then you have some options.
If you have a basement directly under the fire place you can make a safe place to store gas bottles and just put a supply line directly above to the gas fire place. Easy to to replace once every few months and lasts for a bit.

If you have no basement then maybe if space permits a safe place somewhere outside on your wall- hidden away form first sight(but easy access to replace) and run some gas lines to the fire place.

Last option is to keep the gas bottle somewhere in the same room in a safe,ventilated cupboard.. like some people use the a gas stove with a supply bottle right under it. This is the last option (maybe easiest) but safety is a big concern though.

**propane(gas) bottles or cylinders.**

[image]

[image]

**Propane tank**

[image]

Comment: I had to google 'gas bottle'. For those on this side of the pond, that'd typically be called a 'propane tank'. Not sure about the UK, but in the US that would typically be on the outside of one's house and is what most rural residences use for gas supply.

Answer (score 1):

The main options would be:

- keep it as-is and burn the fake logs (they are made from recycled materials and wax. Convenient, but not really a heat source)
- convert to gas (or propane given your location)
- convert to a pellet system. Chris mentioned wood pellets. Corn pellets are also popular in may parts of the country.
- consider leaving it wood, but add a wood stove insert. They make high efficiency inserts these days that can work as a good heat source.
- electric (not a fan of those...it's not a fire...and IMHO would look cheesy in an old fire place)
- candles. Pretty. Obviously not a heat source.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably going to depend on your reason for not wanting to keep a wood burning fireplace.  But assuming that the chimney is good, you might also want to consider a wood pellet fireplace insert.